# How would a groups of scientists, engineers, architects, survival experts, smiths and archeologists survive back in the mesolithic-era-ish of humans?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, humans, science-in-society, ancient-history

A group of 25 people, which consist of scientists, a musician, a linguist, engineers, architects, survival experts, smiths and archeologists from the year 2021, lets assume all of them are experienced in their fields (btw what I mean by scientists I mean they are experts in natural sciences like chemistry, physics, biology, petrology, geology etc.) get transported back in time in 12,000 BCE in the middle of the lush plains and nearby forests of the fertile crescent. They will be transported back in time with T shirts, pants, and shoes on.

Assuming they would have their immune system adjusted to fit their environment and that they won't spread any pathogens from our world and cause an epidemic, what would they need to do in order to survive in here?

And if they survive and get accepted by a local tribe (idk the chances of that happening but lets assume it happens and the local homo sapiens they meet were friendly), what would they need to do in order to make sure that they contribute and prepare the foundations of progress and develop the culture (including language) of human society and civilization for the following generations to come (such as agriculture, simple machines, the concept of education etc.)?

Side note: They all speak modern english which would prove difficult to convey messages but they should get around that.

(P.S. Just give me a limited list of things and an explanation, not asking for everything just a broad guideline, so the the SE guidelines don't slap me again with the infinite list of things rule and get another question closed, this is my 4th question and I'm kinda frustrated of it happening again.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129624/discussion-on-question-by-the-dingus-lord-how-would-a-groups-of-scientists-engi).

Answer (score 1):

Survivalists will be the key, as long as they are familiar with really rudimentary skills like knapping. Anything beyond basic tricks grandpas show their grandkids will be wasted on the native population provided they don't just kill the intruders outright.

Bones can be used for sharp needles, bark for rudimentary rope, clay soil and straw for shelter. The first two days, the priority is probably going to be shelter and a source of relatively clean water. A week without food is manageable, but water will be key. Bookish people will be left to construction and foraging duty, while the survivalists do hunting. All in all a group of 20 will need to successfully hunt a wild deer or so every few days to stave off starvation. The closest you could get to someone else aside from survivalists even approaching usefulness would be structural engineers that could help in simple construction, but even that is likely to be such a simple task that I doubt their information would bring much more to the table other than a second pair of hands that don't need to be coddled during construction.

A single generation will barely be enough to teach anyone more than simplest of tasks. Maybe weaving reeds to a mat to sleep on or to have a bit of shelter from the wind, possibly two forked sticks on the sides of a fire to spitroast a piece of meat over it. Drying racks to cure meats for winter and migration purposes.

To maximize the tribe's potential, all efforts should be related to food and shelter, to increase their numbers and nutrition. With excess calories and effective hunting tactics, they'd be able to have more free time, and come to some discoveries on their own, possibly as fast as the upcoming centuries.

Comment: Oh I see! So get necessities at bay first, then introduce stuff like pulleys, the lever, and maybe a rudimentary wheel with wagons and stuff, I mean, they are located in the place where mesopotamia started so I'm guessing resources would be abundant and the collective handy work of people, plus qualified ones, could form simple machines like that.  Not to mention they do have archaeologists so they might know a thing or two about the resources of the time.